Изменение подсети
Возможно ли наиболее безболезненно изменить родную подсеть микротика 192.168.88.0 на допустим 192.168.99.0? Выполнив это какой-либо регуляркой. Что бы, во всем конфиге микрота были изменены айпишники одной подсети на другую?
/ip address remove [find address=192.168.88.] и че нить add 192.168.99.

Mikrotik умеет сохранять бэкапы и в текстовом формате.  Winbox > Terminal — export file=my_config_backup.rsc. Переходим в Files, находим по названию и сохраняем файл на комп. Открываем в текстовом редакторе, правим при помощи автозамены, на всякий случай переименовываем, запиховываем его обратно и восстанавливаемся из нового конфига.

Нашел такое решение
внешняя ссылка Change LAN Subnet
